# Проблема с открытием файлов

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

У меня такая проблема в работе с файлами: если я указываю полный путь к файлу типа "`D:\\Progect\\sum_control\\Files\\file1.txt`", то программа работает нормально, но если я данную конструкцию заменю на "`file1.txt`", то появляются ошибки типа

> 'Cannot read file "file1.txt"'

Хотя файл находится в той же директории, что и исходный код. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Думаю, что, исполняясь, программа меняет директорию. Проверьте.

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что исполнимый файл будет (1) скомпилирован в том же каталоге, где лежат исходники? (2) запущен из каталога, где скомпилирован, (3) не меняет текущего каталога?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл должен находится в директории с скомпилированной программой, а не исходным кодом. Если это Visual Studio, то в папке Debug/Release

Comment: Неверно. Файл должен находиться в _текущем_ каталоге программы. Он совпадает с каталогом, где лежит программа, только если программа запускается из этого каталога (а не из другого с указанием полного пути) и не меняет свой текущий каталог.